# How to disable strip after lipo in qbs?

Tags: qbs

I've noticed some problems with qbs on macOS: building universal binary leads to inevitable strip for the universal binary.

> qbs.exec: Running external process; full command line is: "/usr/bin/lipo -create -output /path_to_projects/proj_name/build/default/product_name.4f35c325/product_name /path_to_projects/proj_name/build/default/product_name.eyJhcmNoaXRlY3R1cmUiOiJ4ODZfNjQifQ--.16d81f6a/product_name /path_to_projects/proj_name/build/default/product_name.eyJhcmNoaXRlY3R1cmUiOiJhcm02NCJ9.f20a385c/product_name"
> qbs.exec: Additional environment: ()
> lipo product_name [product_name]
> qbs.exec: Running external process; full command line is: "/Users/user/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -S /path_to_projects/proj_name/build/default/product_name.4f35c325/product_name"

Is there any ways to make unstripped universal binary with qbs?

Comment: I suspect this is an oversight in the implementation. You could create a task at bugreports.qt.io.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like a bug, I created https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QBS/issues/QBS-1647